# Grails dependency injection via autowiring doesn't work

Tags: grails, dependency-injection, autowired

I have a Service, called `Mailer`, and a controller, which should use this service:

```
class DocumentController {

    def mailer

    def publish = {
        mailer.sendReport()
    }

}
```

But when I call `publish` I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method sendReport() on null object
```

Why doesn't the dependency injection work here?

Comment: Do you see any initialization issues with your service in the log? If the bean fails to initialize properly this is a typical symptom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grails is all about conventions.  I think mailer needs to be called mailerService.  It needs to be in the services directory.  Controller needs to be in the controllers directory.

From the documentation

"A service contains business logic that can be re-used across a Grails application. In Grails a service is a class that ends in the convention "Service" and lives in the grails-app/services directory. A service can be created with the create-service command:"

Comment: Thanks! The Problem was the missing `Service` in the class name.